# What kind of curtain rod should I buy for these brackets?

Tags: doors, windows, curtain-rail

I'm trying to figure out what style of curtain rod to buy for these brackets on my doors. One end has a circular hole and the other end has a rectangular opening. They are 27" apart.

I live in California and my building has been around since the late 1920s.

What kind of curtain rod I should buy?

[image: circular hole]
[image: rectangular opening]

Comment: Those brackets are for a 'pull down blind' aka 'roller shade', not for curtains. You would pull down the opaque blind and it would internally catch. A short tug to release it and it would recoil itself. You can see these in cartoons when they abruptly spin up and fwap-fwap-fwap at the top position. [Roller Shade bracket](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Bali-Cut-to-Size-Outside-Mount-Roller-Shade-Bracket-38-0151-00/202194899)

Comment: That's it. I'm going to see if I can use the phrase "fwap-fwap-fwap" in a sentence today...

Comment: Congrats, @DanielGriscom, you just did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those brackets are for a 'pull down blind' aka 'roller shade', not for curtains. You would pull down the opaque blind and it would internally catch. A short tug to release it and it would recoil itself. You can see these in cartoons when they abruptly spin up and fwap-fwap-fwap at the top position. [Roller Shade bracket](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Bali-Cut-to-Size-Outside-Mount-Roller-Shade-Bracket-38-0151-00/202194899)

[image]
            <sub>Outside Mount Roller Shade Bracket</sub>

If you are determined to put curtains on the door(s) then chip off the many layers of paint covering the screws and cut through the paint around the base before attempting removal. A heat gun or powerful hair dryer will speed this process up but be careful about overuse unless you plan to ultimately strip the door down to bare wood and refinish.

The curtain rod you purchase may or may not come with a pair of appropriate curtain rod brackets. There are [a wide variety available](https://www.homedepot.com/s/curtain%2520rod%2520bracket?NCNI-5) for different applications. For a small curtain rod meant to accommodate the window in a door, there's a good chance the existing mounting screw holes will be reusable.

Comment: Jeeped? A new contributor? Really??? Oh, new to [diy.se], welcome! Most small curtain rods do come with the mounting brackets. At least, all the ones we've purchased of late have. Actually the big ones come with brackets, too.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome,FreeMan. I quickly checked a few curtain rod kits and curtain rod replacements on an on-line site. The majority had brackets but some of the replacement rods didn't so I just settled with *'may or may not come with'* since the OP seemed to be looking for a replacement for the (wrong) existing brackets.